# click event on mapView in IOS not working in titanium studio

Tags: ios, iphone, annotations, click, titanium

I'm creating an app with some annotations. Now I need to handle a click on costume the annotations. I have tried to put the click event on each annotation or on the mapView but none seams to work. I have tried this:

this is how I create my costume annotations:

```
var pins = [];

var imgTemp = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : "/images/p_" + keys[j] + ".png"
});

var alturaImg = imgTemp.toBlob().height;
var larguraImg = imgTemp.toBlob().width;
var alturaImgNova = deviceHeight * 0.04;
var fator = alturaImg / alturaImgNova;
var larguraImgNova = larguraImg / fator;

var annottion = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude : pontos2[keys[j]][i].Lat,
    longitude : pontos2[keys[j]][i].Long,
    pincolor : MapModule.ANNOTATION_VIOLET,
    customView : Ti.UI.createImageView({
       height : alturaImgNova,
       width : larguraImgNova,
       image : "/images/p_" + keys[j] + ".png"
    }),
    draggable : false,
    id : id
});

pins.push(pins);
mapview.addAnnotations(pins);
```

click on the annotation:

```
MyAnnotation.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

click on the mapView:

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

On android the mapView click event works fine. The problem is on IOS.

Comment: I discovered that when I define ' title:'test' ' the click event works. the problem is I don't need the InfoWindow. I have also tried to put a title and hide the Info Window but the showInfoWindow : false, seams not to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IOS, you have to set canShowCallout to false.

create annotation :

```
var annotation = MapModule.createAnnotation({
        latitude : annotations[i].latitude,
        longitude : annotations[i].longitude,
        myid : i
    });

if (OS_IOS) {
        annotation.image = "/images/icn_map_location.png";
        annotation.canShowCallout = false;
    } else {
        annotation.customView = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            width :  48,
            height : 58,
            backgroundImage :  "/images/icn_map_location.png"
        });
    }
```

click on the mapView:

```
mapView.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: can you put hear an example pleas how your ar doing it? I have tried to change te customView to image bot has not solved my problem. I have read that it is necessary to have a title defined for the annotation. If it does not have any title the click event doesn't work in IOS

Comment: I have tried the example you put @HamidMly but the problem persists. the click event only works in android and not in IOS. The click event only works when I define a title for the annotation.

Comment: Thanks @HamidMly, I kept exactly the same solution that I have posted but added the line annotation.canShowCallout = false; from your code and it works perfectly for android and IOS. Thanks